# Textrevisioning in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-schema, scd

at the moment I am working on a cms that should support text revisioning. Because sometimes I tend to overcomplicate things I thought I ask here for improvements and advise.

I have the following 4 tables:

**article**

```
ID INT PK
createdAt DATETIME
updatedAt DATETIME
```

**article_revision**

```
ID INT
articleID INT FK
headline VARCHAR(255)
teaser TINYTEXT
text LONGTEXT
createdAt DATETIME
```

**tag**

```
ID INT
name VARCHAR(20)
createdAt DATETIME
```

**article_revision_has_tag**

```
articleRevisionID INT PK FK
tagID INT PK FK
```

So the `article` is the holder for general information of an article. An `article` can have one or more `article_revision`s. All assigned tags are saved in reference to the `article_revision`. This is so I can keep track of changing tags.

But the last thing I am not quite sure about is: How can I create a history like it is implemented in stackoverflow? For example the text is changed from three different users over time and at the end the author does a rollback to the first version. How would the database table look like to keep track of this?

I thought about something like this:

**article_revision_history**

```
ID INT PK
articleID INT FK
articleRevisionID INT FK
userID INT FK
note VARCHAR(255)
createdAt DATETIME
```

With this I have references to `article`, `article_revision` and an optional `user` table. If I use `ORDER BY createdAt DESC` I would get the revision history. Starting with the newest one.

Is this the best way for a revisioning history? If not what could be the best way?

And if we assume that this will be a software solution where it could be possible that over 100 articles are added to the database in a day (with more than one revision), is a full history tracking maintainable? What are your experiences?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Found a [similar question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/137421/patterns-for-versioning-relational-data-in-a-mysql-database) on programmers.

Comment: This concept is called Slowly Changing Dimensions (SCD). I suggest to take a look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension) and Google a bit about it. Make sure the model you choose fits your requirements; changing the model over time can be a painful process (which I can tell from experience, unfortunately).